# Draw a semi-circle button iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to draw a semi-circle button. I'm having trouble both drawing the semi-circle and attaching it to the button I made in xcode. The button in xcode has constraints pinning it to the bottom of the screen and centering it. I reference the button in my view controller and then try to override it to a semi-circle as follows. I am getting a blank button. I also hard coded in the coordinates from the storyboard of where the button is. Is there a better way to do that?

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 113.0, y: 434.0),
radius: 10.0, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)

let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath

sunButton.layer.mask = circleShape
```

Comment: To clarify, this is within a function that I am calling on viewDidLoad and the reference to my button is sunButton!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that your shape layer is positioned way outside the buttons bounds. If you just add the shape layer as a subview of your button's layer you'll see the problem:

```
button.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
```

[image]

You have to adjust the arc center point, so that the arc lies within the button's bounds:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPointMake(button.bounds.size.width / 2, 0), radius: button.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath
button.layer.mask = circleShape
```

And you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: It was very helpful for me but I got an issue. The button is also click able outside the coloured area(actual area of button) how can I disable this functionality ?

Comment: Hi @UmairAfzal. In your UIButton subclass you can override `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` to define which area of your button is clickable. Have a look at this tutorial for details: http://www.planet1107.net/blog/custom-shape-uibutton-tutorial/

Comment: @joern Hi if i want the reverse of this arc,what i have to do?

Comment: @Elan Set `clockwise` to `false`

Comment: @joern if i do like this my view is not visible to me,code i have used is as follows:-

'   [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, 0)     radius:self.bounds.size.height startAngle:0  endAngle:M_PI clockwise:false];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeView = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    shapeView.fillColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    shapeView.path=[path CGPath];
    self.layer.mask=shapeView; '

Comment: You have to set the arc's center y to `size.height` instead of `0`. Because the circle is drawn from the bottom to the top now.

Comment: I want to set to reverse can you please help me. I want code in swift. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 update:**

```swift
let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: button.bounds.size.width / 2, y: 0), radius: button.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
button.layer.mask = circleShape
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5:**

```
    // semiCircleDown
  let circlePath =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: shapeView.bounds.size.width/2, y: 0), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        //semiCircleUp
  let circlePath =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: shapeView.bounds.size.width/2, y: 0), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 2 * .pi, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        //quarterCircleRightDown
  let circlePath =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.width, startAngle: 2 * .pi, endAngle: .pi * 3/2, clockwise: true).cgPath

        //quarterCircleLeftDown 
  let circlePath =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: shapeView.bounds.size.width, y: 0), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.width, startAngle: .pi * 3/2, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        quarterCircleRightUp
  let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: shapeView.bounds.size.height), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.width, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi/2, clockwise: false).cgPath

        //quarterCircleLeftUp
  let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: shapeView.bounds.size.width, y: shapeView.bounds.size.height), radius: shapeView.bounds.size.width, startAngle: .pi/2, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: false).cgPath

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = circlePath.cgPath
shapeView.layer.mask = shape
```

Comment: What is circleShape?