# Making an any size button?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button which is semicircle in shape.

Inside button class

```
 layoutSubviews() { 
    createSemiCirclePath()
 }

 func createSemiCirclePath(){
       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.clipsToBounds = true
       semiCircleShape.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 , y:0), radius: self.frame.size.width/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true).cgPath
       self.layer.addSublayer(semiCircleShape) 
       self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

But I want like this:

[image]

If I'm trying

```
 func createSemiCirclePath(){
       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.clipsToBounds = true
       semiCircleShape.path = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 , y:0), radius: self.frame.size.width/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true).cgPath
       self.layer.mask = semiCircleShape
       self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

My button is

[image]

It is also allowing to click under 50% of height of button, which I don't need.

(in 1 code)

The problem is, only the black portion should be click-able and blue portion should be hidden, i.e., it should clip to the sublayer.

Any suggestion is appreciated .
Thanks.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561585/iphone-button-with-non-rectangle-shape

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310108/5215474

Comment: yes, but the full rectangle button is click-able not only the semicircle portion.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can subclass UIControl class, it class contains methods to handle touch events  also it class handle target/selection routine.
Also this class do not contain custom draw logic as UIButton.
In you example you should only extend UIControl and add

```
controlInstance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Is it not your class?

Comment: class semiCircle:UIButton this my class

Comment: why you can not change to class semiCircle:UIControl ?