# How to set UIView in semi circle in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift5

I want to crop my UIView to the semi-circle and that will support all iPhone devices. Here, we can't set height and width to fix. I am using a multiplier.

Here is some of the SO answer I checked.

[How to crop the UIView as semi circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193029/how-to-crop-the-uiview-as-semi-circle)

[Draw a semi-circle button iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309000/draw-a-semi-circle-button-ios)

It's work but for the fix height and width not with multiplier and I am targeting universal devices.
Below is the image for semicircle UIView.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not necessary to take UIView if this thing is done by any other objects like UIImageView or UIButton then that's fine. I'll update the question once it has done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just modified the circle code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45193832/14733292) link code. The problem is in the original code it used the initial frame when again layoutSubviews method called at that time `semiCirleLayer == nil` this condition is prevented from the update bezier path.

```
class SemiCirleView: UIView {
    
    var semiCirleLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height)
        let circleRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        
        semiCirleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        semiCirleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        semiCirleLayer.name = "RedCircleLayer"
        
        if !(layer.sublayers?.contains(where: {$0.name == "RedCircleLayer"}) ?? false) {
            layer.addSublayer(semiCirleLayer)
        }
        
        // Make the view color transparent
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! Please check in 11Pro it has some space in trailing and I set UIView trailing to zero.

Comment: @YogeshPatel check my ss working fine with all sizes. Can you please add your code and screenshot?

Comment: My bad my code was overriding your code I checked it perfectly now it's working fine. Thank You much!